# Is it possible to trigger a javascript keypress event not in an input or textarea tag?

Tags: javascript, events, keypress

I was wondering if you can trigger a javacript keypress event but not within an input out textarea tag?

What I want to a achieve is when the user presses any key anywhere on the page an alert shows up saying : You pressed a key.

Here's my code : http://codepen.io/willydev/pen/LkZAob

```
function pushbtn(event){
var x = event.keyCode;
alert("You pressed"+x)
}
```

I'm not sure want event listener to use or where I should put it.

Answer (score 9):

Of course you can, simply delegate the `keypress` event-handler to the `document`:

```js
function pushbtn(event) {

  // retrieving the keyCode of the pressed key:
  var keycode = event.keyCode,

  // finding which letter was generated, using
  // String.fromCharCode():
    key = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
  console.log('You pressed ' + key + ' (keyCode: ' + keycode + ').');
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', pushbtn);
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

If you wish to exclude those `keypress` events triggered within `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements:

```js
function pushbtn(event) {
  var keycode = event.keyCode,
    key = String.fromCharCode(keycode),

    // finding the element on which the event
    // was originally fired:
    source = event.target,

    // an Array of element-types upon which
    // the function should not fire (to prevent
    // interfering needlessly with the UI and
    // user-expectations):
    exclude = ['input', 'textarea'];

  // finding the element-type (tagName) of the element
  // upon which the event was fired, converting it to
  // a lower-case string and then looking in the Array
  // of excluded elements to see if the element is held
  // within (-1 indicates the string was not found within
  // the Array):
  if (exclude.indexOf(source.tagName.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
    console.log('You pressed ' + key + ' (keyCode: ' + keycode + ').');
  }
  return;
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', pushbtn);
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
}
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<input />
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Upvoted, but this seems a bit out of date: according to MDN, the `keypress` event is deprecated in favor of `keydown` and/or `keyup`. Further, MDN states that `event.keyCode` is deprecated in favor of `event.key`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
document.onkeypress = function(event){

if(event.keyCode == 32){
document.write("Space key pressed");
};

};
```

Of course you can change the keyCode depending on the key you need, or delete the entire keyCode section if you don't care which key is pressed.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the event-listener on document.

```js
    function pushbtn (event){
      var x = event.charCode; //not keyCode
      alert("You pressed"+x);
    }

    //adding event listner on document
    document.addEventListener('keypress', pushbtn);
```

Use `charCode` instead of `keyCode` but still `keyCode` will give you the keycode of the key(number)
Use `key` it is perfect for your case.
Code will look like this

```js
    function pushbtn (event){
      var x = event.key;
      alert("You pressed :"+x);
    }

    //adding event listner on document
    document.addEventListener('keypress', pushbtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the whole document as your event target and then attach it to either a JavaScript or jQuery keypress event listener.

```
$(document).keypress(function() {
   alert("You pressed a key!");
});
```